# FileSystems.getDefault().getPath() vs Paths.get() and resource leakage

Tags: java, path, filesystems, nio, resource-leak

If I use `FileSystems.getDefault().getPath()` it holds resource at `FileSystems.getDefault()`. Few tools like sonar, coverity give high impact issues of resource leak for using this.

If I replace it with `Paths.get()` all the such tools quietly accept this and there is no error or warning of resource leak.

If we see the implementation of `Paths.get()`, it is literally doing `FileSystems.getDefault().getPath()`

My question here is, how does java handle resource leak for `Paths.get()` because the code is exactly same but we don't have reference to `FileSystems.getDefault()` to explicitly close it?

Comment: To me, this looks like a missing check in the tools. If you report it to them, I think they would quickly plug this hole.

Answer (score 2):

Your tools are reporting a false positive. That's because the declared type returned by `FileSystems.getDefault()`, `FileSystem`, implements `Closeable`. That means that ideally you should close it. However, the default file system is an exception (it even throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`). Your tools cannot make that distinction.

This happens more often than you'd think. Some examples I've seen too often:

- The result of `Objects.requireNonNull`. The input is returned as-is, but if the input is `AutoCloseable` my IDE treats it as a new resource.
- The input stream or reader from a servlet request, and the output stream or writer from a servet response.

There are some cases where tools and IDEs can be smart. For instance, if I declare a variable as `ByteArrayInputStream`, `ByteArrayOutputStream`, `StringReader` or `StringWriter`, then my IDE knows they don't need to be closed. However, when I return these from a method as `InputStream`, `OutputStream`, `Reader` or `Writer` respectively, my IDE starts complaining if I don't close them.

If you know that it is a false positive, you can use `@SuppressWarnings("resource")` to ignore warnings by some tools. That can often be applied to single variables:

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource") FileSystem defaultFS = FileSystems.getDefault();
Path path = defaultFS.getPath("foo");
```

However, even then sometimes your tools will complain, and you have to suppress the resource warnings for the entire method. If that's the case, try to keep your method (and therefore the scope of the warning suppression) as small as possible; split off code to a new method if needed.

Comment: You mean we don't need to explicitly close ```FileSystem``` got from ```FileSystems.getDefault()``` Java will close it for us as it implements ```Closable```?

Comment: The `FileSystem` class implements `Closeable`, but for the default `FileSystem` the `close()` method throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`. That means you cannot close it even if you try, either using try-with-resources or by explicitly calling `close()`.

Comment: Ok got it!!
```close()``` throws ```UnsupportedOperationException``` we cannot call it, makes sense.

But then what exactly java does with the resource opened by ```FileSystems.getDefault()```, this is what I am trying to understand and search on google and I couldn't find anything for it

Answer (score 0):

This is a false positive when running in a Linux environment.

When running in a Linux environment, FileSystems.getDefault() is an exception to this rule. Actually, if you try to close, it will throw an exception. Check the source code

```
  public final void close() throws IOException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
```

https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/unix/classes/sun/nio/fs/UnixFileSystem.java#L155